# Laravel Query Builder WHERE NOT IN

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have the following sql query

```
SELECT * FROM exams WHERE exams.id NOT IN (SELECT examId FROM testresults)
```

how can I convert it into Laravel query builder format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `whereNotIn` with a closure:

```
$result = DB::table('exams')->whereNotIn('id', function($q){
    $q->select('examId')->from('testresults');
})->get();
```

Comment: do I still need to add ->get() at the end?

Answer (score 1):

**with Eloquent :**

```
$result = Exams::whereNotIn('id', function($q){
        $q->select('examId')->from('testresults');
    })->get();
```

Comment: As this question has an accepted answer from 2015, it would be much more useful to anyone viewing this question if you could [edit] your answer and explain how your answer differs from the accepted answer and in which circumstances you believe it would be a better approach.