# Laravel Query Builder WHERE NOT IN with multiple WHERE clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have following query,

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE approved='1' 
and users.id NOT IN (SELECT donations.user_id FROM donations where month='1' 
and year='2016');
```

I have followed [Laravel Query Builder WHERE NOT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361461/laravel-query-builder-where-not-in)
and converted my query like this,

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('approved','=',1)->whereNotIn('id', function($q){
        $q->select('user_id')->from('donations')->where('month','=','$month')->where('year','=','$year');
        })->get();
```

But its not working, can anybody help me out where i am making mistake.
how can I convert it into Laravel query builder format?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put your **$month** and **$year** variables in quotes.

Replace

```
->where('month','=','$month')->where('year','=','$year')
```

with

```
->where('month','=',$month)->where('year','=',$year)
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked. Thanks.
I forgot that its a variable.

Comment: @SAMEERKHAN If it works, you should accept the answer.